# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react react-router. Help!

Tags: node.js, npm, reactjs, react-router, webpack-dev-server

```
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.3.2
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-router@3.0.5
```

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm WARN redux-async-connect@1.0.0-rc4 requires a peer of react@0.14.x but none was installed.
>
> npm WARN redux-async-connect@1.0.0-rc4 requires a peer of react-router@2.x.x but none was installed.
>
> npm WARN UpsignCorp@1.0.0 No repository field.

Добрый день! Подскажите, до какой версии нужно обновить `react-router` чтобы восстановить зависимости?

Answer (score 0):

Данный пакет требует:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": "0.14.x",
    "react-router": "2.x.x",
    "react-redux": "4.x.x" 
},
```

Но врятли Вам захочется устанавливать столь устаревшую версию React. Сам пакет не обновлялся более года. Вместо него можно использовать [redux-connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-connect), который совместим с последними версиями React:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "prop-types": "~15.x.x",
    "react": "15.x.x",
    "react-redux": "~4.x.x || ~5.x.x",
    "react-router": "~2.x.x || ~3.x.x" },
```